# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock works properly only while debugging

Tags: html, registerclientscriptblock

Using RegisterClientScriptBlock I have no problem whith displaying the warning alert but after I close the pop up the binding becomes a real mess. The weird thing is that when I try to debug it and go with F10 the binding is ok. 
This this a code behind method:

```
protected void lvContratFonds_OnItemDeleting(object source, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e) 
{
    try
    {
        ListView lv = (ListView)source;

        int contratId = int.Parse(((HiddenField)lv.Parent.FindControl("hdnContratId")).Value);
        int anneeFiscaleId = int.Parse(((HiddenField)lv.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("hdnAnneeFiscaleId")).Value);
        int contratFondId = int.Parse(((HiddenField)lv.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("hdnContratFondId")).Value);
        ImageButton lnkSupprimerContratFonds = (ImageButton)lv.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("lnkSupprimerContratFonds");

        string errMsg = String.Empty;
        errMsg = ContratFondBLL.DeleteSingleContratFond(contratFondId, ((PageProjet)Page).ProjetId); 
        if (errMsg.Length == 0)
        {
            ContratsFondsTransBLL.DeleteAllContratFondTransByContratId(contratFondId, ((PageProjet)Page).ProjetId);
                       }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "ClientScript", "alert('" + Resources.GPWebResource.errContratFondDelete.ToString() + "')", true);

        }
        bindContrats();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}
```

```
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="wideContainer">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltlOrphanWarning" runat="server" Text="OrphanWarning"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
            <div class="contentDiv">
                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="showbtn" ID="btnAjoutContrat" runat="server" Text="AjouterContratAddContract" OnClick="btnAjouterContrat_Click" Visible="false" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>

   <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="wideContainer">
        <div class="contentDiv">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratId" runat="server" Value='("ContratId") ' />
            <div class="titleCellContrats smallCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlContratNum" runat="server" Text="ContratNum"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats largeCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlType" runat="server" Text="Type"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlDateDND8" runat="server" Text="DateDND8"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlDtOctroi" runat="server" Text="ApprovalDateOctroi"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlFundsTot" runat="server"  Text="ValContratTotal"/></div>
            <div class="modCellTitle">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contentDiv">
            <div class="contentCellContrats smallCell"><asp:Literal ID="numeroContrat" runat="server"/></div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats largeCell boldText"><asp:Literal ID="typeContrat" runat="server" /></div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:Literal ID="dateDND8" runat="server" /></div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats mediumCell">
                <asp:Literal ID="dateOctroi" runat="server"/>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxOctroi" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Enabled="false"  />
            </div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:Literal ID="ltlTotal" runat="server"/></div>
            <div class="modCellContrats">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnModifierContrat" runat="server" Tooltip="ModifierModify" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/edit_16x16.gif" CommandName="Edit" Visible="false" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDeleteContrat" runat="server" Tooltip="Supprimer" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/delete_16x16.gif" CommandName="Delete"  OnClientClick="SuppContratDeleteContract" Visible="false"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentDiv">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltlCommentaires" runat="server"/>
        </div>

        <div class="contentDiv">
            <div class="titleCellContrats Fonds">
                <div class="alLeft"><asp:literal ID="ltlfunds" runat="server"  Text="ValContrat"/></div>
                <div class="alRight smText"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAjouterContratFond" runat="server" Text="AjoutEF" OnClick="lnkAjouterContratFond_Click" Visible="false"/></div>
            </div>
               <asp:ListView 
                    ID="lvContratFonds" runat="server" 
                    InsertItemPosition="None" 
                    OnItemDataBound="lvContratFonds_OnItemDataBound" 
                    ItemPlaceholderID="afficherFonds"  
                    OnItemEditing="lvContratFonds_OnItemEditing" 
                    OnItemUpdating="lvContratFonds_OnItemUpdating" 
                    OnItemCanceling="lvContratFonds_OnItemCanceling" 
                    OnItemDeleting="lvContratFonds_OnItemDeleting" 
                    OnItemInserting="lvContratFonds_OnItemInserting" 
                    OnItemCreated="lvContratFonds_OnItemCreated" >
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="afficherFonds" />
                    </LayoutTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="contentDiv">
                            <div class="contFondsRows">
                                <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds"><asp:Literal ID="lblAnneeFiscaleEF" runat="server" /></div>
                                <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds"><asp:Literal ID="lblFondsContrat" runat="server" /></div>
                                <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds">
                                    <strong><asp:Literal ID="ltlDeltaTitle" runat="server" Text="Delta" />:</strong>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltlContratFondDelta" runat="server" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="modCellCntrFonds">
                                    <asp:ImageButton class="smText" ID="btnModifierContratFonds" runat="server" Tooltip="ModifierModify" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/edit_16x16.gif" Height="10" Width="10" CommandName="Edit" Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton 
                                        class="smText" 
                                        ID="lnkSupprimerContratFonds" 
                                        runat="server" 
                                        Tooltip="Supprimer" 
                                        ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/delete_16x16.gif" 
                                        Height="10" 
                                        Width="10" 
                                        CommandName="Delete" 
                                        OnClientClick="SuppFondsDeleteFunds" 
                                        Visible="false"/>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratFondId" runat="server" Value='("ContratFondId") ' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratId" runat="server" Value='("ContratId") ' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAnneeFiscaleId" runat="server" Value='("AnneeFiscaleId") ' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnEF" runat="server" Value='("efID") ' />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                   <EditItemTemplate>
                        <div class="contentDiv">
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnEditTemplate" runat="server" Value='True' />
                            <div class="contFondsRows">
                                <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEF_AF_Prog" runat="server" DataTextField="DisplayField" DataValueField="EF_ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEF_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="false"></asp:DropDownList></div>
                                <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds"><asp:TextBox ID="txtFondsContrat" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> $</div>
                                <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds">
                                    <strong><asp:Literal ID="ltlDeltaTitle" runat="server" Text="Delta" />:</strong>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltlContratFondDelta" runat="server" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="modCellCntrFonds">
                                    <asp:ImageButton 
                                        class="smText" 
                                        ID="btnEnregistrerContratFonds" 
                                        runat="server" 
                                        Tooltip="EnregistrerRegister" 
                                        ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/save_16x16.gif" 
                                        Height="12" 
                                        Width="12" 
                                        CommandName="Update" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton class="smText" ID="btnAnnulerContratFonds" runat="server" Tooltip="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/undo1_16x16.gif" Height="12" Width="12" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"/>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="FondMontantObligAmntReqd" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtFondsContrat" />
                                    <asp:CompareValidator id="CheckFormat1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFondsContrat" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Currency"  Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="InvalidCurrency" />

                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratFondId" runat="server" Value='("ContratFondId") ' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratId" runat="server" Value='("ContratId") ' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAnneeFiscaleId" runat="server" Value='("AnneeFiscaleId") ' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnEF" runat="server" Value='("efID") ' />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="transPanel" class="contentDiv" runat="server">                                
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlTransactions" runat="server"> 
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <uc2:FMASTransControl ID="uc2FMASTransControl" runat="server" ContratMode="true"  />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                       </div>

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                   <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <div class="contentDiv">
                            <div class="contFondsRows">
                                <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEF_AF_Prog" runat="server" DataTextField="DisplayField" DataValueField="EF_ID" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="false"></asp:DropDownList></div>
                                <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds"><asp:TextBox ID="txtFondsContrat" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> $</div>
                                <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds">
                                    <strong><asp:Literal ID="ltlDeltaTitle" runat="server" Text="Delta" />:</strong>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltlContratFondDelta" runat="server"  Text="AD_InfoNA" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="modCellCntrFonds">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAjouterCF" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Tooltip="EnregistrerRegister" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/save_16x16.gif" Height="12" Width="12" CommandName="Insert" ValidationGroup="insertFondGroup"/>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAnnulerCF" runat="server" Tooltip="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/undo1_16x16.gif" Height="12" Width="12" OnClick="btnAnnulerCF_Click" CausesValidation="false" />

                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="FondMontantObligAmntReqd" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtFondsContrat" ValidationGroup="insertFondGroup" />
                                    <asp:CompareValidator id="CheckFormat1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFondsContrat" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Currency"  Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="InvalidCurrency" />

                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratId" runat="server" Value='("ContratId") ' />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>

                </asp:ListView>

            </div>

        <div class="contentDiv">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <div class="wideContainer">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratId" runat="server" Value='("ContratId") ' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnEditTemplate" runat="server" Value='True' />    
        <div class="contentDiv">
            <div class="titleCellContrats smallCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlContratNum" runat="server" Text="ContratNum"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats largeCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlType" runat="server" Text="Type"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlDateDND8" runat="server" Text="DateDND8"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlDtOctroi" runat="server" Text="ApprovalDateOctroi"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlFundsTot" runat="server"  Text="Delta"/></div>
            <div class="modCellTitle">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contentDiv">
            <div class="contentCellContrats smallCell"><asp:TextBox ID="txtContrat" runat="server" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox></div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats largeCell">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeContrat" runat="server" DataTextField="NomChampFieldNm" DataValueField="TypeContratId"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats mediumCell"><uc1:DateControl ID="dateDND8" runat="server" /></div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats mediumCell">
                <uc1:DateControl ID="dateOctroi" runat="server"/> 
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpOctroiAfterDND8" runat="server" ControlToCompare="dateDND8$txtDate" ControlToValidate="dateOctroi$txtDate" 
                ErrorMessage="ErrDateOctroi " Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ToolTip="ErrEndDate ">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxOctroi" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" onclick="GetTodayDateForOctroi();"  />
            </div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:Literal ID="ltlTotal" runat="server" Text="" /></div>
            <div class="modCellContrats">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEnregistrerContrat" runat="server" Tooltip="EnregistrerRegister" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/save_16x16.gif" CommandArgument='("ContratId") ' CommandName="Update" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAnnulerContrat" runat="server" Tooltip="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/undo1_16x16.gif" CommandArgument='("ContratId") ' CommandName="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentDiv paleBackground <%# Container.DisplayIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "altRow"  bordered">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentairesContrats" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength="250"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajx:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="tbweCommentairesContrats" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCommentairesContrats" WatermarkText=" tbweCommentContats" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />
        </div>
       <div class="contentDiv">
            <div class="titleCellContrats Fonds">
                <div class="alLeft"><asp:literal ID="ltlfunds" runat="server"  Text="ValContrat"/></div>
                <div class="alRight"><asp:LinkButton class="smText" ID="lnkAjouterContratFond" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:GPWebResource,AjoutEF" OnClick="lnkAjouterContratFond_Click" Visible="false"/></div>
            </div>
            <asp:ListView 
                ID="lvContratFonds" 
                runat="server" 
                InsertItemPosition="None" 
                OnItemDataBound="lvContratFonds_OnItemDataBound" 
                ItemPlaceholderID="afficherFonds2"  
                OnItemEditing="lvContratFonds_OnItemEditing" 
                OnItemUpdating="lvContratFonds_OnItemUpdating" 
                OnItemCanceling="lvContratFonds_OnItemCanceling" 
                OnItemDeleting="lvContratFonds_OnItemDeleting" 
                OnItemInserting="lvContratFonds_OnItemInserting" 
                OnItemCreated="lvContratFonds_OnItemCreated" >

                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="afficherFonds2" />
                </LayoutTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="contentDiv">
                        <div class="contFondsRows">
                            <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds"><asp:Literal ID="lblAnneeFiscaleEF" runat="server" /></div>
                            <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds"><asp:Literal ID="lblFondsContrat" runat="server" /></div>
                            <div class="contentCellContrats ContFonds">
                                    <strong><asp:Literal ID="ltlDeltaTitle" runat="server" Text="Delta" />:</strong>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltlContratFondDelta" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="modCellCntrFonds">
                                <asp:ImageButton class="smText" ID="btnModifierContratFonds" runat="server" Tooltip="ModifierModify" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/edit_16x16.gif" Height="10" Width="10" CommandName="Edit" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:ImageButton class="smText" ID="lnkSupprimerContratFonds" runat="server" Tooltip="Supprimer" 
                                ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/delete_16x16.gif" Height="10" Width="10" CommandName="Delete" 
                                OnClientClick="SuppFondsDeleteFunds" Visible="false"/>

                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratFondId" runat="server" Value='("ContratFondId") ' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratId" runat="server" Value='("ContratId") ' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAnneeFiscaleId" runat="server" Value='("AnneeFiscaleId") ' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnEF" runat="server" Value='("efID") ' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:ListView>
        </div>
        <div class="contentDiv">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
    <div class="wideContainer">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnContratId" runat="server" Value='("ContratId") ' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnEditTemplate" runat="server" Value='True' />                 
        <div class="contentDiv">
            <div class="titleCellContrats smallCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlContratNum" runat="server" Text="ContratNum"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats largeCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlType" runat="server" Text="Type"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlDateDND8" runat="server" Text="DateDND8"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlDtOctroi" runat="server" Text="ApprovalDateOctroi"/></div>
            <div class="titleCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:literal ID="ltlFundsTot" runat="server"  Text="Delta"/></div>
            <div class="modCellTitle">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contentDiv <%# Container.DisplayIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "altRow" ">
            <div class="contentCellContrats smallCell"><asp:TextBox ID="txtContrat" runat="server" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox></div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats largeCell">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeContrat" runat="server" DataTextField="NomChampFieldNm" DataValueField="TypeContratId"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats mediumCell"><uc1:DateControl ID="dateDND8" runat="server" /></div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats mediumCell">
                <uc1:DateControl ID="dateOctroi" runat="server" />
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpOctroiAfterDND8" runat="server" ControlToCompare="dateDND8$txtDate" ControlToValidate="dateOctroi$txtDate" 
                ErrorMessage="ErrDateOctroi " Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ToolTip="ErrEndDate ">*</asp:CompareValidator>
            </div>
            <div class="contentCellContrats mediumCell"><asp:Literal ID="ltlTotal" runat="server" Text="" /></div>
            <div class="modCellContrats">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAjouterContrat" runat="server" Tooltip="Add " ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/add_16x16.gif" CommandName="Insert"  />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAnnulerContrat" runat="server" Tooltip="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/WebUI/images/icones/undo1_16x16.gif" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnAnnulerAjouterContrat_Click"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentDiv bordered">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentairesContrats" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength="250"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajx:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="tbweCommentairesContrats" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCommentairesContrats" WatermarkText="tbweCommentContats" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />
        </div>
    </div>              
    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please explain what you mean by "the binding becomes a real mess"? Do you get duplicates?

Also, are you able to post the code for your bindContrats() method?

Edit 1:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(lvContratFonds, typeof(ListView), "ClientScript", "alert('" + Resources.GPWebResource.errContratFondDelete.ToString() + "')", true);
```

Edit 2:

```
if (errMsg.Length == 0)
{
    ContratsFondsTransBLL.DeleteAllContratFondTransByContratId(contratFondId, ((PageProjet)Page).ProjetId);
    bindContrats(); // re-bind data
}
else
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "ClientScript", "alert('" + Resources.GPWebResource.errContratFondDelete.ToString() + "')", true);
    /* don't re-bind! */
}
```

Comment: I wish to add this code but it is kind of too long. What it does it bind the main list which has several items and each of them can have its own list of items. Each child list has an user control in update panel. So it is like a chain and what I get at the end - I see the only one item in parent list and somehow all child lists. Weird.

Comment: If I could attach the screenshots it would be more clear. In aby case I could understand if the binding became screwed always but it happens only I run application without debuging. If I remove scriptblock- all goes fine. If you have any idea what I can do...I'll really appreciate any help. If I need to provide more info- just let me know but unfortunately I cannot copy the whole class code.

Comment: Ok, the ListView code you posted, is this for the main list? Or is it for one of the child lists? Are you able to post all markup, or is that too big also?

If you have many UpdatePanels working together you may be getting a race condition of some kind.

Please try edit 1

Comment: No, it didn't work. It gives the error that parameter (lict view control) is null. So I replaced it with ListView lv = (ListView)source : ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(lv, typeof(ListView), "ClientScript", "alert('" + Resources.GPWebResource.errContratFondDelete.ToString() + "')", true);
No error but no pop up :-)

Comment: Are you able to post full markup for your Main listview and child listviews?

Comment: I have tryed to update marlup but the part of it was cut off.This part should be at the top:

Comment: <asp:ListView ID="lvContrats" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lvContrats_ItemDataBound" OnItemEditing="lvContrats_OnItemEditing" 
OnItemCanceling="lvContrats_OnItemCanceling" OnItemUpdating="lvContrats_OnItemUpdating" OnItemDeleting="lvContrats_OnItemDeleting" 
OnItemInserting="lvContrats_OnItemInserting" InsertItemPosition="None" OnItemCreated="lvContrats_OnItemCreated">

Comment: Ok thanks.

I notice you have a syntax error in your markup here:

<div class="contentDiv paleBackground <%# Container.DisplayIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "altRow"  bordered">

Is this present in your code, or just a problem with copy and paste?

There are two more like this further down too.

Comment: Should be: <div class="contentDiv paleBackground <%# Container.DisplayIndex % 2 == 0 ? "" : "altRow" %> bordered">

Comment: Another question: is your main ListView "lvContrats" also inside an UpdatePanel? Or does the Delete function cause a complete page postback? I also notice that your Delete image button calls a client-side script function: SuppFondsDeleteFunds() what does this do?

Comment: In your 'lvContratFonds_OnItemDeleting' function, when you call 'errMsg = ContratFondBLL.DeleteSingleContratFond(contratFondId, ((PageProjet)Page).ProjetId);', if 'errMsg.Length' is not 0 does that mean that the delete failed? If so, I think you are meant to say 'e.Cancel = true;'. If no modification to the data, try not re-binding the data. See my Edit 2 to see what I mean...